# Possible to use this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-field[field-name=FNAME instead of [data-name="FNAME" ]') in a record-edit-form ;

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I'm using  `<lightning-record-edit-form >`  and hence  lightning-input-field  .  In the  default way of using lightning-record-edit-form there is no need of much manipulation and code. Right now I have to split my page( visible section) in to two and do all kinds of locally saving the values entered in the fields while switching between my page sections.   By adding   attributes like this , data-name="webaddress" , I can get handle on the fields.  What I really wanted to avoid is using an additional attribute , data-xyz , on all fields , instead I wanted to make use of the existing , field-name={companyNameFieldAsAnExample} attribute in a template.querySelector.  Is there a way to do that? I tried

```
let field = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-field[field-name="'+this.companyNameFieldAsAnExample.fieldApiName+'" ]');
```

let fieldVal = field.value;
But this doesn't work. Any ideas? Or this is not accessible using field-name? ( may be it is a dynamic value like ID inside LWC)

Comment: are you trying to update a field programmatically on save or on load?

Comment: have you tried add a [data-name] attribute to the <lightning-input-field> element and querySelect by the [data-name] attribute?

Comment: @Lanjinest That is the question I'm asking. I can do using data-name. Can I use the existing field-name param if so how?

Comment: @CalvinOKeefe  I'm forced to display single record with many fields in multiple sections ( using next and back buttons ). Since I started with record-edit-form and single page ( the way SF does it ) and moved toProd, I have to now use that code base to split in to multiple pages sections. When one section is visible and you go to other section , previous section entered data is not maintained ( as the use case for record-edit-form I believe is all in single page -just like SF does ). So here I'm manually storing entered field values and when section becomes visible rendering it ( ugly )

Comment: I do not think you can use the existing field-name attr, the output DOM element do not have the 'field-name' attr, so your picker will not be able to get that exact element you want...